# How to find <title> and <form> using xpath query

Tags: php, xpath

I'm using `xpath query` to find `<title>` text and occurrence of `<form>`.. My code is as follows

```
$pokemon_doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); 
if(!empty($html)){ 

        $pokemon_doc->loadHTML($html);
        libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

        $pokemon_xpath = new DOMXPath($pokemon_doc);

        $pokemon_row = $pokemon_xpath->query('/title');
        if($pokemon_row->length > 0){
        $data["title"]="Yes";
        }
    }
```

But its not working any idea how to do this?

Comment: What is a "*pokemon xpath query*"?

Comment: You are looking for the root node only, and expecting it to be `<title>`. To find all `<title>` elements at any level in the document, you need to use `//title`

Comment: <title>Untitled Document</title> I just want the text content that is "Untitled Document"

Comment: @AmalMurali Looks like he got the idea [here](http://anchetawern.github.io/blog/2013/08/07/getting-started-with-web-scraping-in-php/). Nithin, I suggest only using "pokemon" in your variable names if you are searching for pokemon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$pokemon_row = $pokemon_xpath->query('//title');
$data["title"]="";
if($pokemon_row->length > 0){
    foreach($pokemon_row as $row){
       $data["title"].= $row->nodeValue . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but how get text content <title>Untitled Document</title> "Untitled Document"